# [Vue warn]: Error in render: “TypeError: Cannot read property ‘name’ of undefined”

Tags: vue.js

I get the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property ‘name’ of undefined”

if I go to deep in the object.

Timeline.vue

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="card card-default">
                <div class="card-header">Timeline</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <post v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id"></post>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Post from './Post.vue'

export default {
    data () {
        return {
            posts: []
        }
    },
    components: {
        Post
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$http.get('/posts').then((response) => {
            console.log(response.body)
            this.posts =response.body
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

post.vue

```
<template>
<div class="media">

    <div class="media-left">

    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
        <strong>test</strong>
        <strong>{{ post.user.name }} </strong> 
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   props: [
        'post'
    ]
}
</script>
```

Then why I get the error?
I suppose some problem with {{ post.user.name }}.

Comment: You should post the code executed from the `/posts` route. But if I had to guess, you're not loading the post user relation. So you should probably use eager loading `Posts::with('user')->get()` in your controller. When you're writing `$post->user->name` in PHP, Laravel makes sure the user is loaded on the fly, but if you return a JSON response in your controller without the loaded user, the client JS code can't load that relation data.

Comment: Adding either the post array or one post as an example would help out

Comment: Yes . I check http://localhost:8888/posts . It shows [{"id":1,"user_id":1,"body":"Necessitatibus cumque pariatur in excepturi.","created_at":"2018-04-20 07:48:56","updated_at":"2018-04-20 07:48:56","user":{"id":1,"name":"eunice","email":"eunice@gmail.com","created_at":"2018-04-05 08:20:13","updated_at":"2018-04-05 08:20:13"}},

Comment: My post controller is below 
public function index(Request $request, Post $post)
    {
        return $post->with(['user'])->latestFirst()->get();
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the post prop in the template like so. otherwise it's undefined in the child component (post).

```
<div class="card-body">
    <post 
        v-for="post in posts" 
        :key="post.id"
        :post="post">
    </post>
</div>
```

Comment: **otherwise it's undefined in the child component** this is not correct, the prop='post' in the child component='post' will be one string if pass `post` like `<post post="post">`; that is why the error threw at `user.name` not `post.user`