# Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" [Vue warn]

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I got the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Vue file:

```
<tr v-for="user in fields.data" :key="user.id">
    <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.password }}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" @click="edit(user.id)">
            <span class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="mdi mdi-edit"></i>
            </span>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Script:

```
edit(id) {
    this.users = this.fields[id];
    console.log(this.users);
},
```

Comment: what do you have in `fields.data` ?

Comment: its nothing, sorry, i accidentally added it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39755336/angular2-cannot-read-property-name-of-undefined)

Comment: Sorry, but its not the same

Comment: No? That doesn't help at all or offer any insight into your issue? Error is pretty darn explicit. Asked yourself why no warning on `user.id`?

Comment: Shoot. Linked wrong one. **Possible duplicate of [Vue warn: Error in render: “TypeError: Cannot read property ‘name’ of undefined”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49943702/vue-warn-error-in-render-typeerror-cannot-read-property-name-of-undefine)**

Comment: You need to tell us more about `this.fields`—specifically where it comes from, and how.

Comment: Since my english is bad, i cant explain more detail to u guys..
and now i found a solution..
Anyway thanks u guys so much xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually occurs when you try to access a property of an object that does not yet exist (usually because it is created async, with an API request for example). If this is your case, simply tell the template to wait for the object to exist with an v-if.

```
<template v-if="fields && fields.data">
  <tr v-for="user in fields.data" :key="user.id">
    <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.password }}</td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" @click="edit(user.id)">
            <span class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="mdi mdi-edit"></i>
            </span>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

Remember that you cannot set the v-if on the same tag as the v-for.